# C++ makefile building multiple dll and project structuring

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, makefile

I have tried searching for an answer but to no avail, so given that my project has got the following structure

```
makefile
./src
   strings.cpp
   networking.cpp
./bin
   strings.dll
   networking.dll
./build
   strings.o
   networking.o
./include
   strings.h
   networking.h
./lib
   boost
```

I am very new to Makefiles and from the research I have done so far I have managed to get this together (not very complicated, I know)

```
CC = g++ 
SRC = src/strings.cpp
OUT = bin/strings.dll
OBJ = build/strings.o 
INC= -I include

all: strings.dll

strings.dll: strings.o
    $(CC) -shared -o $(OUT) $(OBJ) 

strings.o: $(SRC) 
    $(CC) $(INC) -DBDLL -c $(SRC) -o $(OBJ)
```

The issues/questions I have are

1- It always goes through the whole compilation process, even when I have not changed the source code ?

2- How could I make things more 'effective' ? I saw examples of people using wildcards and such, but I had difficulty following along. Could I use wildcards to begin with since I want separate dlls for each target ?

3 - Lets say I introduced `algorithms.h and algorithms.cpp` what would be the recommended way of including that in the build ?

Thanks for any help, really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First. Whole compilation process goes because make search for target "strings.dll" but build bin/strings.dll. So if you replace it to

```
bin/strings.dll: strings.o
     $(CC) -shared -o $(OUT) $(OBJ)

bin/strings.o: $(SRC) 
     $(CC) $(INC) -DBDLL -c $(SRC) -o $(OBJ)
```

build of targets (bin/strings.o and bin/strings.dll) will be performed only if prerequisite is changed.

Second - basically wildcards are used for search all files inside the directory something like this: `$(whildcard *.cpp)` evaluates to all cpp file inside the current directory. So you can write something like this:

```
all_sources = $(wildcard *.cpp)
all_objects = $(addprefix bin/,$(all_sources:.cpp=.o))

all: bin/strings.dll

bin/strings.dll: $(all_objects)
    <how to build strings.dll from objects>

bin/%.o: %.cpp
    <how to build objects inside bin dir from cpp of current dir>
```

Third - makefile is not build system itself it is just a tool that has domain specific language. You can write your own build system using make. If you want ready build you better to study automake/cmake/... many of them.

Also it is good beginning to start using make tool. Don't stop and you will surprise how much power inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer...really helped more than I asked for